# Why is my question voted for being duplicate of another totally different question?

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21641/what-age-is-too-old-for-becoming-a-good-international-tournament-player) is flagged as "duplicate" of [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/can-i-improve-my-chess-or-am-i-too-old). However, what I ask is:

> Am I being a stargazer (or simply put, a fool) by attending
>   **international tournaments**, or can I somehow improve my game to compete
>   with **players around the world**?

whereas in the referred question, OP is asking:

> I am a very poorly rated player, about 1100 on **chess.com**.
>   Am I too old to **start** chess?
>   I sometimes feel bad after a loss, especially if I lose against a lesser-rated player than me. **Does anyone else get this feeling?**

These two questions differ on two basic things:

1. I am seeking to be better at real-life tournaments, whereas the other question as about getting better online.
2. I already know how to play chess, and play it regularly, whereas the other question asks if it is too old to **start** chess.

These being stated, why is my question perceived as a duplicate of the referred question?

Answer (score 3):

They are essentially the same question. Your two basic things are actually very minor details, that don't affect the answer.

1. The rules are the same whether playing online or in person. You're asking to improve at the same game.
2. If you'd read the duplicate carefully, they said they'd been playing for a year, and hadn't improved much. In fact, they stated a goal of becoming an 1800+ player.

Comment: The only similarity between an online game, and a live tournament game is how the pieces move, and the winning conditions. Besides that, every single thing differ such as not being able to use an electronic device, not moving the pieces using mouse, not being able to listen to music, and not being able to talk. This is why I deliberately wrote "tournament" player. The referred question asks about online rating of 1800+. Not ELO.

Comment: How the pieces move and the winning conditions are the similarities that matter. Also, it's Elo, after Arpad Elo, who developed the rating system. ELO is the Electric Light Orchestra, an Enlglish rock band.